# How do you use an existing AppleID on iOS App Store without providing a credit card number?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, ipad

I already have an Apple ID, made at Apple.com. Now, when I want to access the App Store from my iPad, I am told that I have to review my information. On the credit card page, I am not presented with a "None" option, even though I am in the United States.

What can I do to proceed without entering this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an existing Apple ID and then enroll it into the store.

The "none" option only exists for new accounts as a one-time (or limited count) event for that device thanks to scammers and people that manipulate app store ratings with factory reviews and paid downloads.

You can usually make a brand new Apple ID following these steps:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034

It's generally a bigger pain to have two Apple ID, so I would encourage you to not set up a new ID just to avoid the temporary delay of getting a legitimate address and card for temporary use.

Once you have your account verified, you can use store credit for just about everything on the store.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do the following when at the Credit Card page

- Click on Paypal
- Click on 'To redeem a code, click here'

From this new workflow, you will be able to get to the same page with the 'None' option

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a valid option.

Comment: what worked for me was to choose Paypal as payment type, then cancel when asked to login to Paypal. After that "None" option was available. (might have to change country to US temporarily) See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139634/44901

Comment: This only works once you are past the point where the iOS app store asks for a billing address and credit card.

Comment: It probably also depends on the country. The Dutch store also has an option for 'Clickandbuy' as another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

go to your account in iTunes and then sign out, still beeing signed out, "purchase" a free app in iTunes youll then be promted to sign in, do so and then head over to your account and billing information the "none" option has now have appeared, choose it and save your information. and you are all done...

***IF** that doesnt work try this check your purchase history for any unpaid bills, rather outstanding balance. Take care of that and the None option should appear.*

[apples description](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1918?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Nope, tried that already.

Comment: thats really weird, i did it less then an hour before i saw your post and it worked great, try this check your purchase history for any unpaid bills, rather outstanding balance.

Take care of that and the None option should appear.

Comment: this is a completely new account.

Comment: hmmm, bit of a puzzle, here is apples description on how it SHOULD work 

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534

Comment: I'm guessing since Apple's steps involve creating the Apple ID during the download free app process, it's not possible to proceed with an "existing" Apple ID without entering a credit card.

Answer (score -1):

Go to apple store, for example look for Youtube app, which is free app, you will be prompted to sign in, create new account under icloude, follow the on screen instruction, on account and billing screen, choose the "none" option,and submit the form you are done. so easy and straight forward.

Comment: This doesn't work for an existing AppleID - it only works if you make up a new AppleID and only for a limited few accounts (3 currently)